# Slider for Select List (Text, Numbers etc) in Views Exposed Filters

Tags: views, javascript

I am trying to implement a vertical slider-like select list inside my views-exposed-filters as shown in the image below (on the left sidebar, vertical slider)

[image: Vertical Sliders for Select list]

I am using Drupal 7 and Views 3. I have tried Better exposed filters module but I don't think it has such a feature. How can I achieve this? (See updates below)

Thanks

UPDATE: I have also tried **Views Contextual Range Filter** and **Select with Style** modules but couldn't get any of them working as desired.

UPDATE 2: One thing I have realized is, I am trying to show a an exposed filter for a term reference field, named 'Style' (based on a taxonomy term), so actually the field itself is not a multi-value field, hence it is not a select list. That is why Select with Style module doesn't work here. Is there a way to tweak my field/Views to make it work with one of mentioned modules?

Answer (score 1):

There is another module called [Views Contextual Range Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/contextual_range_filter)

> Views Contextual Range Filter is a simple plugin for Views that adds the option to contextually filter not just by a single value, but also by range.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for [Select with Style](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_with_style):

> Slide with Style, contains a field widget to enter numbers or list values via sliders when creating content and also to filter using this widget in Views. This includes double-handled sliders to input "in-between" ranges.

Comment: I have tried this module as well. But now that you mentioned here I will install it and try again. I think I just couldn't get it working before

Comment: Also, do you think Apache Solr Search module could be helpful for this situation?

Comment: @Shamil.F next time please list all the things you tried in your question. Providing solutions that failed for you is a waste of time - both your and mine.

Comment: @Shamil.F If you already tried that module, you should include that in your post

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I know I should include it. it's just that it slipped my mind while I was going over what I have tried so far, since I removed the module after trial.

Comment: One thing I have realized is, I am trying to show a an exposed filter for a term reference field, named 'Style' (based on a taxonomy term), so actually the field itself is not a multi-value field, hence it is not a select list. That is why Select with Style module doesn't work here. Is there a way to tweak my field/Views to make it work with one of mentioned modules?